# Olingo with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, odata, spring-restcontroller, olingo

I am using [this tutorial](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/tutorials/read/tutorial_read.html) and it works for a simple java web application. Now I want to convert it to Spring Boot. I remove the web.xml and add the following two annotations to DemoServlet

```
@RestController
public class DemoServlet extends DispatcherServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoServlet.class);

    @RequestMapping("/DemoService.svc/*")
    protected void service(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            // create odata handler and configure it with CsdlEdmProvider and Processor
            OData odata = OData.newInstance();
            ServiceMetadata edm = odata.createServiceMetadata(new DemoEdmProvider(), new ArrayList<EdmxReference>());
            ODataHttpHandler handler = odata.createHandler(edm);
            handler.register(new DemoEntityCollectionProcessor());

            // let the handler do the work
            handler.process(req, resp);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            LOG.error("Server Error occurred in ExampleServlet", e);
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I also change the HTTPServlet to DispatcherServlet.

Now I am only able to access one end point. i.e.

```
http://localhost:8080/DemoService.svc/
```

The metadata end point is not working. It returns the service document instead of xml content.

```
http://localhost:8080/DemoService.svc/$metadata
```

Can somebody explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `@Configuration` and Map your servlet in it like the following

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean odataServlet() {

    ServletRegistrationBean odataServRegstration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet(),
            "/DemoService.svc/*");
    Map<String, String> initParameters = new HashMap<>();
    initParameters.put("javax.ws.rs.Application", "org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.rest.app.ODataApplication");
    initParameters.put("org.apache.olingo.odata2.service.factory",
            "com.metalop.code.samples.olingo.springbootolingo2sampleproject.utils.JPAServiceFactory");
    odataServRegstration.setInitParameters(initParameters);

    return odataServRegstration;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

user the below code for the process method.

```
    handler.process(new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
        // Spring MVC matches the whole path as the servlet path
        // Olingo wants just the prefix, ie upto /odata, so that it
        // can parse the rest of it as an OData path. So we need to override
        // getServletPath()
        @Override
        public String getServletPath() {
            return "/DemoService.svc";
        }
    }, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following after the handler.register call:

req.setAttribute("requestMapping", "/DemoService.svc");

Answer (score -2):

The best implementation of olingo2 and spring-boot can be found [here](https://github.com/jpenninkhof/odata-boilerplate). I would suggest to take a look at this repository, it is very straight forward and easy.